# My code prints "Not Found" for every line, how do i get it to only print "Not Found" once if the search is unsuccessful?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program needs to be a simple contact book with names, phone numbers, and emails. You need to be able to search people and add a contact. I got the program to save to a text file in a decent enough way and am trying to search the file line by line. I can get it to print the line if it has the searched name but i can not figure out how to get the program to tell if the contact is not found at all. With the current way i have my code, it will say "Contact Not Found" for every line that the name is not in. How would i get it to only say it was not found once if the name is not in the text file?

**What i have tried is:**

```
f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')

def make_contact(name, phone, email):
    f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\n' + 'Name: ' + name + ' Phone: ' + phone + ' Email: ' + email)
    f.close()

menu_input = 0
while menu_input != 3:
    print('\n1. Search Contact\n2. Add Contact\n3. Exit')
    menu_input = int(input("\nChoose Option: "))
    if menu_input == 1:
        name = input ('\nEnter a Name to Search: ')
        with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if name in line:
                    print("\n" + line)
                else:
                    print("\nContact Not Found!")

        f.close()
    elif menu_input == 2:
        f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
        name = input("Enter Name: ")
        phone = input("Enter Phone Number: ")
        email = input("Enter Email: ")
        make_contact(name, phone, email)
```

Ill add a new contact say Timmy, When i search Timmy it will say "Not Found" for every line until it gets to Timmy. It repeats "Not Found" for as many contacts there are before Timmys contact line

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your issue including sample input, sample output, and the code for what you've tried so far

Comment: I strongly recommend using `with` for dealing with files! I see at least 3 areas where you’re not using a context manager, and it already looks complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part of code with `for-else`.

```
    with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if name in line:
                print("\n" + line)
                break
        else:
            print("\nContact Not Found!")
```

It will check `if` condition through `for` loop, when there is a match it will print that line and will break out from the loop. If iteration is over and no match found it will check the `else` condition parallel to `for` loop.

If you wants to print all duplicate records then maintain a flag for match

```
flag = False
with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if name in line:
            print("\n" + line)
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        print("\nContact Not Found!")
```

Comment: This works, Thank you! Now what if had a person with the same name and wanted them both to print? With the code this way wont it stop at the first search result and stop?

Comment: @t.phares yes this will print only first  match. In case of duplicate records you have to maintain the flag.

Comment: Is flag almost like a built in variable or command? The code works perfect now using the flag just want to understand what its doing :)

Comment: @t.phares no flag is just a variable and we set it False to default and when checking for match we changed it to True. You can use any name for this like `found`, `exist` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple flag to your code to determine if it found or not. Implementation would be this:

```
with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    found=False
    for line in searchfile:
        if name in line:
            print("\n" + line)
            found = True
    if not found:
        print("\nContact Not Found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add flag to your loop of searching. Once you found out, you can break the loop too.

```
f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')

def make_contact(name, phone, email):
    f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\n' + 'Name: ' + name + ' Phone: ' + phone + ' Email: ' + email)
    f.close()

menu_input = 0
while menu_input != 3:
    print('\n1. Search Contact\n2. Add Contact\n3. Exit')
    menu_input = int(input("\nChoose Option: "))
    if menu_input == 1:
        flag = False
        name = input ('\nEnter a Name to Search: ')
        with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if name in line:
                    flag = True # here you add flag
                    print("\n" + line)
                    break
            if not flag:
                print("\nContact Not Found!")

        f.close()
    elif menu_input == 2:
        f = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
        name = input("Enter Name: ")
        phone = input("Enter Phone Number: ")
        email = input("Enter Email: ")
        make_contact(name, phone, email)
```